# Covariance formula

Tags: covariance

I'm struggling to understand [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwimq5rl-In5AhWMz4sKHWYPAcsQFnoECC4QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.kent.edu%2F%7Ereichel%2Fcourses%2Fmonte.carlo%2Falt4.7d.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3fClDP84V0yCMhSwGBqYzc) presentation of covariance. It says:

> The variance-covariance matrix (or simply the covariance matrix ) of a random vector $\overline{X}$ is given by:
>
> $$Cov(\overline{X})=E[\overline{X}\overline{X}^T]-E\overline{X}(E\overline{X})^T$$

First of all , what does he/she mean with covariance MATRIX of A VECTOR ? Variance of a vector (covariance with itself) ? But isn't that supposed to be a scalar, not a matrix ?!

Second, if you multiply $\overline{X}$ with $\overline{X}^T$, you get a matrix. How do you get the expected value ($E[\overline{X}\overline{X}^T]$) of that matrix?? It doesn't have multiple layers!!

Then, if you take the expected value ($E\overline{X})$ of $\overline{X}$, it's a scalar! What is the point in multiplying it with its transpose? The transpose of a scalar is itself!

I know that the usual definition of covariance is

$$cov(x.y)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})(y_i-\overline{y})}{N-1}$$

THIS makes perfect sense, but the earlier presentation with expected values and vectors is confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of a matrix is defined as the matrix of expected values. Let $\mathbf{M}$ a $p\times q$ matrix, the expectation of $M$ is defined as follows
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{M}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[M_{i,j}\right]\qquad i\in [1,p], j\in[1,q]
$$
so, for example, you can define the expectation of the sum of two matrices
$$
\begin{align*}
            \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}) &= \mathbb{E}([X_{i,j}]+[Y_{i,j}])\\
&= \mathbb{E}[(X_{i,j}+Y_{i,j})]\\
&= [\mathbb{E}(X_{i,j})+\mathbb{E}(Y_{i,j})]\\
&= [\mathbb{E}(X_{i,j})]+[\mathbb{E}(Y_{i,j})]\\
&= [\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X})]+[\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{Y})]
\end{align*}
$$

So, since the **covariance is defined by the expectation**, you can define a covariance also for a vector $\mathbf{X}=[X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n]$ of $n$ jointly distributed random variables $X_i$ (in particular for a vector with itself).

So I think that $Cov(\mathbf{X})$ is a shorthand to write the covariance of two random variable vectors, so $Cov(\mathbf{X})=Cov(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})$.

You can find it by the definition. Let $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{X}}$ the covariance matrix
$$
\begin{align*}
            \mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{X}} &= \mathbb{E}\left[(\mathbf{X}-\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{X}-\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X})^\top \right] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[(\mathbf{X}-\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{X}^\top-\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}^\top) \right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\right] - \mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}^\top- \mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}^\top+\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}^\top\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\right] - \mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}\mathbb{E}\mathbf{X}^\top
\end{align*}
$$

Let me know if it's clear. Hope it will help you.

**Bibliography:**
[Random Vectors](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_1_5_random_vectors.php)
[Wikipwdia - Covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think the problem lies in that I dont understand what a random vector is. Am I right that it is something else than a regular vector like [5 8 1]'

Comment: A random vector of size $n$ is a vector composed of $n$ random variables.
So it's not just a regular vector, but a vector where each entry is a stochastic variable, so each entry depends on random events.
You can see it also as an array of functions.
I hope now the term sounds better.
Check the first bibliography link